# How to add different element in inner array using array function in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to add different array element into inner array?

Suppose, I have following two arrays.

```
$arr1 = [20=>['id'=>20,'aaa'=>1],21=>['id'=>21,'aaa'=>2]];

$arr2 = [20=>['id'=>20,'bbb'=>1],21=>['id'=>21,'bbb'=>2]];
```

How can I achieve following result using array functions?

```
$arrOutput = [20=>['id'=>20,'aaa'=>1,'bbb'=>1],21=>['id'=>21,'aaa'=>2,'bbb'=>2]];

Array
(
    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [aaa] => 1
            [bbb] => 1
        )
    [21] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [aaa] => 2
            [bbb] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: you might be looking for  `array_merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_replace_recursive` does that:

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($arr11, $arr2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php